# Usage error in subprocess call to Linux file command

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am trying to use `file` to determine what type a file is. In stderr, I keep getting a usage message in `stderr` "Usage...." which tells me I am doing something wrong with the arguments but not WHAT is wrong. This is my code below. For more context, `from_file_path` is a temporary file used to store downloaded info. Other subprocess calls work on this file, so I know there is nothing wrong with the file itself.

```
subprocess.run(["file", from_file_path], check=True, shell=True)
```

Comment: Btw, I know using Shell=True is generally not good, but there is no user input in this case so should be fine I think

Comment: Very, very short summary from the linked duplicates: `subprocess.run(['file "$0"', from_file_path], check=True, shell=True)` does what you're asking for, because the first list entry is treated as code for a shell to execute, and later ones are that shell's positional arguments starting from `$0`.